# Git pull on remote host with Fabric

Tags: git, bitbucket, fabric

I'm trying to write deploy script in fabfile.py. This is my code:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.user = 'user'
env.hosts = ['my_host']
env.dbname = 'foo.bar'
env.dbuser = 'pg_user'
env.dbpass = 'pg_user'
code_dir = '/cygdrive/d/folder'


def deploy():
    with cd(code_dir):
        run('git pull')
        run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
        run('manage.py migrate --all')
        run('net stop Apache2.2')
        run('net start Apache2.2')
```

When I try **fab deploy**, I get the error:

```
    [my_host] Executing task 'deploy'
    [my_host] run: git pull
    [my_host] out: Host key verification failed.
    [my_host] out:
    [my_host] out: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    [my_host] out:
    [my_host] out: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    [my_host] out: and the repository exists.
    [my_host] out:
Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
```

The git pull command should pull from bitbucket.org repo (ssh). It is added to the known_hosts file (cloned the repo previously). Both machines are using Windows.

Running git pull from the command line on the remote computer works, but it won't run from the Fabric deploy script!

Any ideas?

Comment: Solution may be found by finding the difference between the environment where git pull works and the env created by the fabric script. Check user account used on the cmd-line and compare the contents of that ~/.ssh/ directory to the PATH_TO_HOME_DIRS/pg_user/.ssh/user setup that is used by the python script.

Comment: @RobKielty, you were right. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got sorted it out!

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: Yes, answer by @RobKielty was right.